# Copy tables excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to copy tables from another workbook into my "extract" workbook.

This code works, but I need to specify which table I am looking for. I was hoping to use a program that could find the table in the specified sheet, or all the cells which contain data and copy those cells.

```
Sub SelectingTable()

Set Extract = Workbooks("Test1")
Set Pastdue = Workbooks("Past Due Data")

'Look for Past Due table

Pastdue.Activate

  Pastdue.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4").DataBodyRange.Copy

'Paste table in extract    

Extract.Activate

  Extract.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10")


End Sub
```

In this code I am basically looking for table4 in the Past Due workbook and pasting it in my Extract. I am new to excel vba so I hope you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: see if this helps https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hmm do you want to extract a particular table or copy all the tables? For the latter you can just loop through all the tables

```
Sub SelectingTable()
Dim tbl as listObject
Set Extract = Workbooks("Test1")
Set Pastdue = Workbooks("Past Due Data")

'Loop through table
pasteRow = 1 'set which row to paste
For each tbl in Pastdue.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects

      rowsCount = tbl.range.rows.count - 1 'minus header
      tbl.DataBodyRange.Copy extract.worksheets("Sheet1").cells(pasteRow,1)

      pasteRow = rowsCount +3

 next tbl


 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Each sheet has only one table, but I just wanted to specify the sheet and copy the table without having to put the table's lable.